# SSIS fails citing invalid meta data for a specific table

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I recently faced an issue where SSIS packages ran locally, but when promoted as ISPAC files to Azure Data Factories live, failed due to invalid meta data.  I removed the strangly built step with a sproc, only for the next step along to start complaining.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple- my connection string on the live environment (populated by Octopus during deployment) didn't include the "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;"  - without it SSIS falls back to the generic OLEDB driver which means it cannot access some of the SQL specific calls it seems to require to query table meta data in the packages.